# parameter passing in C function

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I have a function written in C

```
FindBeginKey(KeyListTraverser, BeginPage, BeginKey, key1);
```

BeginKey is a pointer before function invoking, and I didn't initiate it, like

```
BeginKey = NULL;
```

In the `FindBeginKey()` function, I assign `BeginKey` to another pointer, and try to print out the current address of `BeginKey` in the function, it works correct.
But when code returns from function, I try to print out the address of `BeginKey` again, it shows `0x0`.

Why does this happen, and if I want to preserve the address assigned in the function, what should I do?

Comment: Can you show us the types of `FindBeginKey` and the types of all of the arguments you pass in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a value out of a function you have to pass *by reference* rather than *by value* as is normally the case with C functions. TO do this make the parameter a pointer to the type you want to pass out. Then pass the value into the call with the `&` (address operand).

e.g.

```
FindFoo(FOO** BeginKey);
```

and call it:

```
FindFoo(&BeginKey);
```

and in the function:

```
*BeginKey = 0xDEADC0DE;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are calling the function like:

```
FindBeginKey(KeyListTraverser, BeginPage, BeginKey, key1);
```

However, when you try to write at the BeginKey address, you're basically passing in a pointer to 0x00. Rather, you need to pass a pointer to BeginKey.

```
FindBeginKey(KeyListTraverser, BeginPage, &BeginKey, key1);
```

If this is isn't what you meant, it would certainly help if you posted a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a parameter in a subroutine, you should pass a pointer of the thing you wanna modify.

```
void subroutine(int* x) {
   *x = 5;   // will modify the variable which x points to

   x = 5;  // INVALID! x is a pointer, not an integer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all the C parameter passing rules are now, so this answer might be a little dated. From common practice in building applications and libraries that those applications called, the return from a C function would contain status, so the caller of the function could make a decision depending on the status code.

If you wanted the function to modify its input parameters, you would pass those parameters by reference `&my_val`, where `int my_val;`. And your function must dereference my_val like this `*my_val` to get its value.

Also, for performance reasons, and address (by reference) might be preferable, so that the your application did not bother copying the parameter's value into a local variable. That prolog code is generated by the compiler. Single parameters, char, int, and so on are fairly straight forward.

I am so used to C++ that passing by reference in C++ does not require dereferencing. The compiler's code takes care of that for you.

However, think about passing a pointer to a structure.

```
struct my_struct  
{                    
  int iType;
  char szName[100];
} struct1;

struct my_struct *pStruct1 = &struct1;
```

If the structure contains lookup data that is filled in once on initialization and then referenced throughout your program, then pass a pointer to the structure by value `pStruct1`. If you are writing a function to fill that structure or alter already present data, then pass a pointer to the structure by value. You still get to alter what the structure pointer points to.

If on the other hand you are writing a function to assign memory to the pointer, then  pass the address of the pointer (a pointer to the pointer) `&pStruct1`, so you will get your pointer pointing to the right memory.